# Why does assertion fail under RUN but not under DEBUG?

Tags: java, unit-testing, assertion

Very strange behavior in a unit test. The code is on another computer so I'll shorthand the main aspect of it.

The problem is

- When I test as RUN the test checks two objects for 10 properties, it fails saying that the object contains 19 properties.
- When I test as DEBUG the test passes for both of the objects where they each have 10 properties.

How the heck is this happening?

```
    @Test
    public void testConverterTwoObjects(){
      InputStream inFile = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(TEST_TWO_OBJECTS);

      try{
          List<MyObject> objs = getConvertedObjects(inFile);
          MyObject mob1 = objs.get(0);
          MyObject mob2 = objs.get(1);

          assertionCheck(mob1);
          assertionCheckTwo(mob2);
      } catch(Exception e){
        // logging
      } finally {
        try{
          inFile.close();
        } catch(IOException ioe){
          // logging
        }
      }
    }

    private void assertionCheck(MyObject t){
      assertNotNull(t);
      assertEquals(10, t.getPropertyCount());
      assertEquals("ALPHA", t.getType());
      ...
    }

    private void assertionCheckTwo(MyObject t){
      assertNotNull(t);
      assertEquals(10, t.getPropertyCount());
      assertEquals("BRAVO", t.getType());
      ...
    }
```

Comment: Have a print statement print all properties out while running.

Comment: You might not use the same classpath in Debug and Run mode and `TEST_TWO_OBJECTS` leads to two differents files ?

Comment: @RobOhRob I have one for just one of the objects to print in the code and it is showing 10 property count and I manually counted the properties in the array which totals 10. But that lead me to put in another System.out.println() to output the 2nd object. Now the test runs and passes every time.

Comment: Any ideas as to why?

Comment: insert print to console statemenet - start you test in run and debug mode - compare outputs for both modes

Comment: Found the issue. It was not a UNIT testing issue/bug. The issue was the blackbox code that I was calling was not properly tracking it's own property counter.

Comment: I despise black box code usage.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem in PyCharm (Intellij IDEA for Python). After searching hours, it turned out that the garbage collector's behaviour is different in debug mode than in run mode.

Comment: That's Python.  The OP is asking about Java.

Comment: That is something that is good to know especially since I'm starting to look into Python. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Makoto i know, but Java also has a garbage collector and pyCharm is very similar to IDEA

Comment: @Sadap:  You're talking about garbage collection during a run of the application.  Irrespective of how similar these IDEs are, Python will never behave the same as Java.